# How to Compare Variable to PictureBox Image

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, visual-studio, picturebox

```
    If PictureBox1.Image = "a.png" Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.b
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.a
    End If
```

It won't work. How do i make this thing working? It shoud check if the picture box is showing the picture *a* , if yes then make it showing picture *b*.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
        If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.b Then
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.a
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.b
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Thats the complete code**

Comment: First of all: project properties: option strict on, option explicit on

Comment: Yes i tried it before, but that still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is a Property of type [System.Drawing.Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) whereas `"a.png"` is a string so you can't compare these things to see if they are equal.

Also `Image` is a reference type, so you must use `Is` to compare it to another reference type.

The following might work:

```
If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.a Then
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.b
Else
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.a
End If
```

Note: Comparing images can be tricky because when you set an Image property it may actually create a copy of the original image, so then comparison later does not work. See [How to compare Image objects with C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384967/how-to-compare-image-objects-with-c-sharp-net)

So taking that into account, it would be a better idea to use a variable to compare the state as this consumes less resources and is far simpler than having to compare images.

Something like the following should work for you:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static showImageA As Boolean
    showImageA = Not showImageA

    If showImageA Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.a
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.b
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: make sure you have Option Strict and Option Explicit On because the code you posted does not compile when you do this and so points out the errors to you.

Comment: Thank you it solved the errors, but it still doesnt change the picture. Can you help me again?

Comment: Sounds like you have another issue then. If you are doing this in a loop then try `PictureBox1.Refresh` after you set the image as a quick fix.

Comment: `Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If PictureBox1.Image Is My.Resources.b Then
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.a
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.b
            PictureBox1.Refresh()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
`